# Check the end of the linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a simple linked list structure and I want to iterate this.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Suppose I created a node whose data is 1 without initializing `next`.

```
Node* test3 = new Node;
test3->data = 1;
```

Since next is not `NULL`, I cannot make a limiting condition when I iterate this linked list.
I don't think there is any way to detect if the memory is allocated.
How could I resolve this?

Comment: you should probably default `next` to equal to `Null`....

Comment: And what exactly stops you from initializing it by nullptr?

Comment: That broken node is a test case for dealing with an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, the `next` member can not be used to determine this, as it has undefined value and any attempt to read from it is undefined behaviour. You need to set it, or ensure it is set. If you can't do this, then you need to keep track of the last via other means, such as storing the pointer to the last node in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using C++ you can add a constructor to the struct, too. This is much safer as you cannot forget to initialize the next pointer:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    Node() : next(0) {}
};
```

When you create a `new Node`, `next` is initilized to `NULL` == 0 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the silliest question....or not, if you're not familiar with linked lists.

Just initialize `next = 0;` every time you make a `new` one.
Then you can set an `if` condition that checks whether the node you're handling has a next in line or it's the last one.

Something like:

```
node* test = new node;
test->data = 1;
test->next = 0;

//[....]

test = test->next;
if (test)
{
    //do what you have to...
}
```

If the `if` condition fails, the previous node was the last one.
You can also set it as:

```
if (test->next) //next != 0
{
    //this is not the last node
}
else //next = 0
{
    //this is the last node
}
```

---

### EDIT 2015_11_26-0154

```
node* test = new node;
test->initialized = 0;
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I wanted to detect uninitilized node.

Comment: You cant, uninitialized pointers always contain something, just you dont know what.  
If anything, you can just add another variable to the structure, something like a `bool initialized` that you'll manually change every time you initialize the node.  
But you'll have to initialize the new variable every time you make a new node anyway.